# C switch question

Tags: c, switch-statement

I'm new to programming and I would like to add to a switch that would take in option cases such as `-aa`, `-aaa`, `-aaaaaa` etc where each of these three cases could serve a singular function in addition to case `a`?

I was thinking...

```
    int option = getopt (argc, argv, "abcd");
    switch(option){
    case 'a': BLAH = TRUE;
              break;
    case 'b': FOO = TRUE;
              break;
    case 'c': BAR = TRUE;
              break;
    case 'd': BAZ = TRUE;
              break;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i<argc; i++){
    if ( argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == 'a' && argv[i][i+2] == 'a' )
       myOption =TRUE;
    }
```

But would this work?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: my problem isnt whether to use getopt(), but its whether or not argv[i][i+2] == 'a' would do what I want it to do

Answer (score 3):

The `getopt_long(3)` function provides command-line parsing to many programs, typically with invocations like this:

```
struct option long_options[] = {
    {"add",         0, 0, 'a'},
    {"binary",      0, 0, 'B'},
    {"base",        1, 0, 'b'},
...
    {"Optimize",        1, 0, 'O'},
    {"preprocess",      0, 0, 'p'},
    {NULL, 0, 0, 0},
};


while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "adf:h::rRVvI:b:BCD:NSm:qQn:XKTWkO:po:", long_options, &o)) != -1)
{
    switch (c) {
    case 0:
        PERROR("Assert, in getopt_long handling\n");
        display_usage(progname);
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'a':
        count++;
        option = OPTION_ADD;
        break;
    case 'd':
        debug++;
        skip_read_cache = 1;
        break;
/* ... and so forth */
```

You might be able to use `getopt_long(3)` to scan an array of inputs to look for multiple inputs (think `add`, `binary`, etc. from the `long_options[]`) that map to a single short option (`a` or `B`).

But if you are more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, there might be a better mechanism available.

Comment: That's `getopt_long(3)` rather than `getopt(3)`, isn't it?  At least, on RHEL 5, `man 3 getopt` describes `getopt(3)` and not `getopt_long(3)`, but `man 3 getopt_long` (on my machine) does describe both.

Comment: @Jonathan, that's what I get for skimming the manpage too quickly :) I was just happy that I typed it correctly in one go... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, this probably would not work. The best way in C (assuming you use Linux) is to use some of the [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Getopt.html) functions that the GNU C library provides. You could also use `if..else if` and `strcmp()` if you just need to process one or two long options.

Last time I checked similar features exist for BSD's libc as well (might be a bit different, though).

Answer (score 1):

`'aaa'` is not integer, not char, and, not any type in the C language.  The expression passed to switch statement should return an integer.  So, switch statement is going to complain there.

For non integer comparisons such as the ones you have listed out, using if-else should be good.